# grep multiple patterns and count how many in the string r

Tags: r, design-patterns, count, match

I got a question about count how many matched pattern in a string

for example,
I got a dataframe 's'

```
index  string
1      'I have first and second'
2      'I have first'
3      'I have second and first and third'
```

and a match pattern vector called toMatch

```
toMatch <-  c('first', 'second', 'third')
```

the final result I want is like:

```
string                              count
'I have first and second'           2
'I have first'                      1
'I have second and first and third' 3
```

now I can only use

```
grepl(paste(toMatch, collapse = "|"), s$string)
```

it will return me which string matches any of element in toMatch, but how can I know how many element are matched?

Any help would be appreciate! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

```
data.frame(string=s$string, count=rowSums(sapply(toMatch, function(x) grepl(x, s$string))))
```

Answer (score 2):

Another possibility that may be faster:

Your Data:

```
dat <- read.table(text="index  string
1      'I have first and second'
2      'I have first'
3      'I have second and first and third'", header=TRUE)

toMatch <-  c('first', 'second', 'third')
```

The Approach:

```
library(stringi)
dat$count <- stri_count_regex(dat$string, paste(toMatch, collapse="|"))
dat

##   index                            string count
## 1     1           I have first and second     2
## 2     2                      I have first     1
## 3     3 I have second and first and third     3
```